# PHP Checkboxes Values

Tags: php

I have the following forms in my buy.php page. This page submits to the checkout.php page.

```
Burger $4.99  <input type="checkbox" name="foods[]" value="burger"/>
Fries  $2.49  <input type="checkbox" name="foods[]" value="fries" />
Pizza  $10.99 <input type="checkbox" name="foods[]" value="pizza" />
Steak  $15.59 <input type="checkbox" name="foods[]" value="steak" />
Ribs   $15.99 <input type="checkbox" name="foods[]" value="ribs"  />

<input type="submit" name="buy" value="Buy Now" />
```

What I wanted to do is that when users presses the Buy Now button, they should be redirected to the checkout.php page which will display the items they bought on the previous page along with the price for each of those items as well as the total of all items. I am able get the value from these input fields by looping through the $_POST['foods'] array which gives the value of each checkbox selected by the user. How would I go about getting the prices of each of the items the user bought so I can calculate and then display the total of those items? Would I have to include more fields? Also, I should mention that I am not yet using database for these pages. Sorry, I'm new to PHP. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should make use of the [label element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1) to provide better access for screen readers and friends and to provide larger click targets for your checkboxes. You should also place your labels after your checkboxes (as that is the conventional layout for that type of form control).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! But please don't send the prices with input fields! They can easily be manipulated!

Comment: There is no such thing as a PHP checkbox, to let others know what is in question, there is `tag` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your server side system should already know what the prices are. You could just keep them in an array, you could use a database (a database is a better idea for long term maintenance and flexibility).

You have the ids of the items, so you just need to look them up in whatever data store you decide to use.

While you *could* mess about with storing the data in the form, it makes it subject to client manipulation (so people could lower the price of whatever they were ordering) and is no simpler then storing the data server side.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you'd have somewhere this data is available, maybe a database, or (ugh) hard-coded into your script with an array:

```
$foods = array(
    'burger' => array('prettyname' => 'Burger', 'price' => 4.99),
    'fries' => array('prettyname' => 'Freedom Spuds', 'price' => 2.49),
     etc...
);
```

You'd use this data source (whatever it happens to be) to generate the checkbox/food list, and then you can use it to look up prices later on.

Comment: Hey thank you for the tip. Another question I had was that where would I define this array? In the buy.php or the checkout.php page? Are my input fields okay or would I need to change foods[] from the name? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should have that saved somewhere (such as a database or a script file) and apply those calculations from there. It's not recommended to integrate it into the HTML/DOM as it is easily changeable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you have produced the price of the items yourself then you already have a list of what they cost. Don't accept the price coming back from the web page as this is in the control of the user, whatever you put there